# Printing a tab in gsub

Tags: r

`data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) gsub("AA", "A\tA", x)))`

The output is `A\tA` instead of `A     A`

Comment: By default R calls `print()` on values to display them. The `print()` function escapes special characters by default. You use `cat()` when you don't want escaping, though you usually don't `cat()` an entire data.frame. So the data should be correct, you are just not expecting how it's being printed to the console. Are you just trying to view the values? Or what is the required output here?

Comment: Correct. I was going by the console output, but after saving the file, the changes as expected were visible. Thanks!